# Merge SQL results

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have to run two separate SQL queries as the databases are on different servers:

```
$link1 = mssql_connect($server1, $SQLUser1, $SQLPass1);
$link2 = mssql_connect($server2, $SQLUser2, $SQLPass2);
$db_Query1 = "SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6
              FROM table;";
$db_Query1 = "SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6
              FROM table;";
$result_id1 = mssql_query($db_Query1, $link1);
$result_id2 = mssql_query($db_Query2, $link2);
```

So at this point I need to merge `$result_id1` and `$result_id2`.

Comment: Please check this link:- http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1918/different-strategies-for-removing-duplicate-records-in-sql-server/. hope help you

Comment: @anantkumarsingh I'm sorry but I can use `DISTINCT`, the problem is that I may I have the same record in the two separate datatables so I only want to remove duplicates from the result in php. I don't want to remove duplicates from the SQL datatable at all.

Comment: Means you want to remove duplicate  from two array by merging it in php?

Comment: So now all I need is to be able to merge them, and the below solution is throwing errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna merge you can use:

```
merge tableB targetTable
using tableA sourceTable
on sourceTable.IsReady = 1 and [any other condition]
when not matched then
insert ...
when matched and [...] then
update ...
```